# (jQuery) unable to select nth-child of a class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm unable to select second class of `notification`.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label for="vzdevek">Vzdevek</label>
  <input type="text" id="vzdevek" />
  <small class="notification">Username required!</small>
</div>
<br />
<div>
  <label for="komentar">Komentar</label>
  <textarea id="komentar"></textarea>
  <small class="notification">Comment required!</small>
</div>
```

I can select ***first*** class for notification using `(".notification:first")`, but for ***second*** class is not working if I use this selector: `(".notification:nth-child(2)")`

> JSfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/ss2pkjsw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that it works only whit `$(".notification:eq(1)")`

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you should use the equals selector `:eq()`, like this:

```
$(".notification:eq(1)")
```

Comment: `.eq()` starts with `0` so using `2` will mean its the `3rd element`

Answer (score 0):

Better use DOM relationship to target [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) element

```
$("#vzdevek").next(".notification").show();
$("#komentar").next(".notification").show();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dialog").hide();
  $(".notification").hide();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".card-link:nth-child(1)").click(function() {

    $("#dialog").dialog({ //autoOpen: false
      buttons: {
        'Add': function() {
          $(".notification").hide();
          $("#vzdevek, #komentar").each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '')
              $(this).next(".notification").show();
          });

          if ($(".notification").is(':visible') == false) {
            alert("OK!");
          }
        },
        'Cancel': function() {
          $(this).dialog('close');
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link data-require="jquery-ui@*" rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script data-require="jquery-ui@*" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="dialog" title="Insert comment">
  <form>
    <div>
      <label for="vzdevek">Vzdevek</label>
      <input type="text" id="vzdevek" />
      <small class="notification">Vzdevek je obvezen!</small>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
      <label for="komentar">Komentar</label>
      <textarea id="komentar"></textarea>
      <small class="notification">Komentar je obvezen!</small>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="card" style="width: 40em; margin: 0 auto;">

  </div>

  <div class="card-block">
    <a href="#/" class="card-link">Add comment</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/nsL9pf8s/)